# Filter grouped data to the rows where grouping changes

Tags: r, dplyr

With these data (below with `dput()`), where `IndIDII` is a grouping column, within which there are multiple observations of `MigStratFact` for each `Year`.

```
> head(Dat)
  IndIDII Year MigStratFact
1 BHS_376 2015      MidDist
2 BHS_376 2016      MidDist
3 BHS_376 2017      MidDist
4 BHS_376 2018    ShortDist
5 BHS_378 2015      MidDist
6 BHS_378 2016    ShortDist
```

I would like to filter `Dat` to the rows where the `lead()` value of `MigStratFact` does not match the current value, AND also retain the current field.

With the code below, for each `IndIDII`, I can filter to the rows where `lead(MigStratFact) != MigStratFact` but am not sure how to also keep the reference (i.e. current) row.

```
Dat %>%
  group_by(IndIDII) %>% 
  filter(lead(MigStratFact) != MigStratFact) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

The desired solution would filter to rows 3,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,15,16.

Many thanks in advance

```
Dat <- structure(list(IndIDII = c("BHS_376", "BHS_376", "BHS_376", "BHS_376", 
    "BHS_378", "BHS_378", "BHS_378", "BHS_391", "BHS_391", "BHS_394", 
    "BHS_394", "BHS_394", "BHS_395", "BHS_395", "BHS_395", "BHS_395"
    ), Year = c("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
    "2015", "2016", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
    "2018"), MigStratFact = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Resident", "ShortDist", 
    "MidDist", "LongDist"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -16L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing to

```
Dat %>%
  group_by(IndIDII) %>% 
  filter(lead(MigStratFact) != MigStratFact | lag(MigStratFact) != MigStratFact)
#    IndIDII Year MigStratFact
# 1  BHS_376 2017      MidDist
# 2  BHS_376 2018    ShortDist
# 3  BHS_378 2015      MidDist
# 4  BHS_378 2016    ShortDist
# 5  BHS_391 2015    ShortDist
# 6  BHS_391 2016      MidDist
# 7  BHS_394 2017      MidDist
# 8  BHS_394 2018    ShortDist
# 9  BHS_395 2017      MidDist
# 10 BHS_395 2018    ShortDist
```

Answer (score 2):

@konvas answer is hard to top, but here another solution. I took the challenge of filtering by index instead of by logical, but I admit it's a bit hard to read.

```
Dat %>%
  group_by(IndIDII) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% c(a <-  which(lead(MigStratFact) != MigStratFact), a + 1))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   IndIDII [5]
   IndIDII Year  MigStratFact
   <chr>   <chr> <fct>       
 1 BHS_376 2017  MidDist     
 2 BHS_376 2018  ShortDist   
 3 BHS_378 2015  MidDist     
 4 BHS_378 2016  ShortDist   
 5 BHS_391 2015  ShortDist   
 6 BHS_391 2016  MidDist     
 7 BHS_394 2017  MidDist     
 8 BHS_394 2018  ShortDist   
 9 BHS_395 2017  MidDist     
10 BHS_395 2018  ShortDist
```